# How to make result set clause variables to automatically match the number of columns of my query's results?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure which loops through 5 different queries.
When using OpenQuery, I need to use result sets in my stored procedure and manually declare the column names, but the problem is my 5 queries doesn't have the same number of columns to be displayed.

How do I make my result set variables to be dynamically set to match the number of columns that I need to display?

Comment: Would the types of these columns also need to be the same here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, If you mean the column names, yes, that would be great if result set variables would totally be the same with the resulting columns of my queries.

Comment: an example would help to understand you. If you would provide sample data and DDL structures then it would be perfect

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev, say for example query 1 has the following results:
FirstName, MiddleName and LastName, 
The result sets should automatically be set to those three as well.

And if my query 2 outputs the following:
ID and Remarks,

The result sets should reflect those 2 column names as well.

Comment: @MikeJoshuaEspiritu give it in your question. The best question would be the one that anyone can copy/paste to SSMS and test it. For example this question is good enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50523628/working-days-of-month