# Working Days of Month

Tags: sql-server

I have these 2 tables and I want to calculate total working days in month. I have this query written which works fine. But in case when there is no data in [tbl_Calendar] table then I get nothing in result.

```
   CREATE TABLE [tbl_Shift](
    [OffDay1] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_Shift_OffDay1]  DEFAULT (N'Sunday'),
    [IsAlternateOffDay2] [bit] NULL,
    [OffDay2] [nvarchar](25) NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO [tbl_Shift] VALUES ('Sunday', 'True', 'Saturday')

    CREATE TABLE [tbl_Calendar](
    HolidayName Varchar(25),
    TotalHoldiays int
    )

    INSERT INTO [tbl_Calendar] VALUES ('Labour Day' , '2');
    INSERT INTO [tbl_Calendar] VALUES ('Mothers Day' , '1');
```

This is the query which works fine when data in both tables exist but when I delete records from [tbl_Calendar] I get nothing. I'm not able to figure out where I'm going wrong. Can anyone help me out here ?

```
        declare @StartDate datetime = '2018-05-01';
        declare @EndDate datetime = '2018-05-31';


    SELECT
        (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate+1)) -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate))
        -ISNULL((CASE WHEN Shifts.IsAlternateOffday2 = 1 THEN (DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate)) END), 0)
        -CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbl_Calendar) THEN SUM(CL.TotalHoldiays) END
        FROM tbl_Shift Shifts, tbl_Calendar CL
        GROUP BY Shifts.IsAlternateOffday2
```

Comment: please use ansi style joins in stead of this ancient type of joins. You have made an inner join here while you need an left outer join

Comment: If you're going to have a "calendar" table, it'd be better to have a *full* calendar table. One which includes *every* day of every year for the foreseeable future and can include column(s), as you have now, to make *which* of the days are holidays. 20 years worth is still less than 10000 rows.

Comment: Also a bit mistified by someone trying to write queries about temporal data when neither table contains any column(s) using `date`, `datetime` or `datetime2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doonie, I don't know where to start on this statement. Your temporary tables aren't appropiate, you are working with dates with no date columns, you are doing a cross join, grouping by a column that doesn't have any sense and making the calculation very complex because of this.

This is the fix you wanted, but you really **need to work on your tables**.

```
declare @StartDate datetime = '2018-05-01';
declare @EndDate datetime = '2018-05-31';

SELECT
    (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate+1)) -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate))
    -ISNULL((CASE WHEN Shifts.IsAlternateOffday2 = 1 THEN (DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate)) END), 0)
    -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CL.TotalHoldiays), 0) FROM [#tbl_Calendar] AS CL)
FROM 
    [#tbl_Shift] Shifts
GROUP BY 
    Shifts.IsAlternateOffday2
```

An example of the broken tables is that your holidays aren't marked with a date, so when using parameters like `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` you don't really know when a holiday applies or not.

Create a full calendar table with one day per row and enough columns that indicate which day is a working day or not, holiday or now, working day including saturdays, etc. This will really help you with date calculations.

Comment: I know there is no date column in these tables but these were just mock tables. I didn't use date or time fields from Shift and Calendar tables because they would have made things bit complex I suppose. But thank you for pointing out I will try to use all specific fields next time. And yes this is what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use Left Outer Join to get Data instead on Inner Join

```
declare @StartDate datetime = '2018-05-01';
declare @EndDate datetime = '2018-05-31';


SELECT
    (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate+1)) -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate))
    -ISNULL((CASE WHEN Shifts.IsAlternateOffday2 = 1 THEN (DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate)) END), 0)
    -CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbl_Calendar) THEN SUM(CL.TotalHoldiays) END
    FROM tbl_Shift Shifts 
    left outer join 
    tbl_Calendar CL on (shifts.column_name = CL.column_name)
    GROUP BY Shifts.IsAlternateOffday2
```

Comment: These both tables are not linked with each other. There is no way I can use Outer Join I suppose.